# Is the Achievements tab now cached?

Tags: support, bug, achievements-dialog

I found this discrepancy today:

[image]

It seems like my most recent upvote to [What do I need to destroy the world?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/149181/62402) isn't being counted here.

So which is it?

- [This bug](/q/296148/335772) resurfacing?
- That tab is now cached, as of this afternoon?
- Some new bug?